# Use remote validation from a modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-3.1

[Remote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#remote-attribute) validation don't work inside a modal.

The modal and ajax method come from this tutorial :

[codaffection.com/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-core-mvc-for-crud-operations-with-modal-popup/](https://www.codaffection.com/asp-net-core-article/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-core-mvc-for-crud-operations-with-modal-popup/)

ViewModel :

```cs
 [Required]
 [Remote(action: "VerifyVIN",controller: "Dashboard")]
 public string VIN { get; set; }
```

DashboardController.cs :

```cs
 [AcceptVerbs("Get","Post")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyVIN(string VIN)
 {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(VIN))
     {
         var result = await _inventoryService.VerifyVIN(VIN);
         return Json(result ? "true" : string.Format("a car for VIN : {0} already exists.",VIN));
     }
     return Json("false");
 }
```

Postman give Code 200 for :
Dashboard/VerifyVIN?VIN=1FUJAPCK25DU88948 (string.Format)
Dashboard/VerifyVIN?VIN=Test ("true")
Dashboard/VerifyVIN ("false")

Of course inside a normal page everything work fine. (ex : https://localhost:5001/Dashboard/Index1 )

Thank you for reading.
Courtesy is okay right ?

Comment: "Remote validation don't work inside a modal."  Have you ever solved the problem? If not, please explain what do you mean about remote validation doesn't work? Do you mean it not show the record exists message when using PostMan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

site.js

```js
verifyVIN = url => {
    var VIN = document.getElementById("VIN").value;
    url = url + "?VIN=" + VIN
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function (res) {
           
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}
```

View.cshtml

```hml
<input onchange="verifyVIN('@Url.Action("VerifyVIN","Dashboard",null,Context.Request.Scheme)')" asp-for="VIN" class="form-control" />
```